# Redshift - Get a value from one column A for each ID in the grouping ID column B based on max value in another column C

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a sql problem (on Redshift) where I need to get the value from column `index` for each id in column `id` based on max value in column `final_score` and put this value in a new column `fav_index`. `score2` equals to the value of `score1` where `index n` = `index n + 1`, for example, for `id` = `abc1`, `index` = `0` and `score1` = `10` the value of `score2` will be the value of `score1` where `index` = `1` and the value of `final_score` is the difference between `score1` and `score2`.

It's easier if you look at below table `score`. This table `score` is a result of a sql query which is shown later below.

```
id    index   score1    score2    final_score
abc1  0       10        20        10
abc1  1       20        45        25
abc1  2       45        (null)    (null)
abc2  0       5         10        5
abc2  1       10        (null)    (null)
abc3  0       50        30        -20
abc3  1       30        (null)    (null)
```

So, the resulting table containing column `fav_index` should look like this:

```
id    index   score1    score2    final_score    fav_index
abc1  0       10        20        10             0
abc1  1       20        45        25             1
abc1  2       45        (null)    (null)         0
abc2  0       5         10        5              0
abc2  1       10        (null)    (null)         0
abc3  0       50        30        -20            0
abc3  1       30        (null)    (null)         0
```

Below is the script to generate table `score` from table `story`:

```
select
    m.id, 
    m.index, 
    max(m.max) as score1,
    fmt.score2,
    round(fmt.score2 - max(m.max), 1) as final_score
from
    (select
         sv.id,
         case when sv.story_number % 2 = 0 then cast(sv.story_number / 2 - 1 as int) else cast(floor(sv.story_number/2) as int) end as index,
         max(sv.score1)
    from
       story as sv
    group by
        sv.id,
        index,
        sv.score1
    order by
        sv.id,
        index
    ) as m
left join
    (select 
        sv.id, 
        case when sv.story_number % 2 = 0 then cast(sv.story_number / 2 - 1 as int) else cast(floor(sv.story_number/2) as int) end as index,
        max(score1) as score2
    from
        story as sv
    group by 
        id, 
        index
    ) as fmt
    on
        m.id = fmt.id
    and
        m.index = fmt.index - 1
group by
    m.id,
    m.index,
    fmt.score2
```

Table `story` is as below:

```
id    story_number   score1
abc1  1              10
abc1  2              10
abc1  3              20
abc1  4              20 
abc1  5              45
abc1  6              45
```

The only solution I can think of is to do something like,

```
select id, max(final_score) from score group by id
```

and then join it back to the long script above (which was used to generate table `score`). I really want to avoid writing such a long script to get just 1 extra column of information that I need.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Update: answer in mysql is also accepted. thanks!

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: please remove mysql as a tag / update your comment as mysql has nothing to do with redshift .

Comment: you are wrong - mysql is not a universal term and it quite different to redshift. a mysql answer to this question would almost certainly not work even with modifications on redshift.

Answer (score 0):

After spending more hours on this and asking people around, I finally figured out a solution by referring to this window function documentation - PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

I basically added 2 x `select` statements at the top and 1 x `where` statement at the very bottom. The `where` statement is to take care of the rows where `final_score` = `null` because otherwise the `rank()` function will rank them as `1`.

My code then becomes:

```
select
    id, index, final_score, rank, case when rank = 1 then index else null end as fav_index
from
(select
    id, index, final_score, rank() over (partition by id order by final_score desc)
from
(select
    m.id, 
    m.index, 
    max(m.max) as score1,
    fmt.score2,
    round(fmt.score2 - max(m.max), 1) as final_score
from
    (select
         sv.id,
         case when sv.story_number % 2 = 0 then cast(sv.story_number / 2 - 1 as int) else cast(floor(sv.story_number/2) as int) end as index,
         max(sv.score1)
    from
       story as sv
    group by
        sv.id,
        index,
        sv.score1
    order by
        sv.id,
        index
    ) as m
left join
    (select 
        sv.id, 
        case when sv.story_number % 2 = 0 then cast(sv.story_number / 2 - 1 as int) else cast(floor(sv.story_number/2) as int) end as index,
        max(score1) as score2
    from
        story as sv
    group by 
        id, 
        index
    ) as fmt
    on
        m.id = fmt.id
    and
        m.index = fmt.index - 1
group by
    m.id,
    m.index,
    fmt.score2)
where
    final_score is not null)
```

And the result is as follows:

```
id    index   final_score    rank     fav_index
abc1  0       10             2        (null)
abc1  1       25             1        1
abc2  0       5              1        0
abc3  0       -20            1        0
```

Result is slightly different than what I stated in the question, however, the fav_index for each id is identified and this is what I needed really. Hope this might help someone. Cheers